# Add class to specific element on scroll in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with 4 DIV's, every DIV has the height of 100vh, that's 400vh. I want to add a specific class to every DIV dependent on the scroll from the top of the page. For example, 0-100vh from the top, class will be added to the first div, the 100-200vh class will be added to the second div (and removed from first), etc. Can someone share a javascript code for this (I don't want to use any library, just vanilla JS)? :)

I tried to Google for it, but I didn't find anything useful for me, only some jQuery scripts...

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<style>
  div {
   height: 100vh;
  }

  .addThis {
    background-color: red;
  } 

</style>
```

Just want to add class .addThis to one of div's depend on scrolled from top.

Comment: look into `document.elementFromPoint` and `window.onscroll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getBoundingClientRect().top` if element in viewport specific class adding and when out of viewport it'll remove.

```js
window.onscroll = function()  {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
  if(elem[i].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0){
    for(j=0;j<elem.length;j++){
      elem[j].classList.remove("addThis")
    }
    elem[i].classList.add("addThis")
  }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}

div {
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom:5px solid;
  background:grey
}

.addThis {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```